# Como contar el tiempo en que la pestaña del cronometro está cerrada

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

estoy tratando de hacer que este cronómetro guarde el tiempo que lleva recorrido y lo logré con localstorage, es decir con el código que tengo el cronometro guarda el tiempo cada vez que refresco la pestaña, el problema empieza cuando cierro la pestaña y la dejo cerrada por un tiempo, el cronometro a pesar de haber guardado el tiempo que llevaba en lugar de sumar todo el tiempo que estuvo cerrada la pantalla reanuda el conteo desde donde se habia quedado, es decir que no tendría que cerrar la pestaña si quisiera que la cuenta sea correcta, intenté hacerlo con otro if en la function .onload, pero lo logro hacer que funcione, no me gustaria cambiar mucho la estructura del código, quiza solo ponerle una condición que haga que si el cronometro estaba corriendo cuando se cerro la pantalla reconozca la ultima vez que precioné el boton para reanudarlo o iniciarlo y que trabaje con ese tiempo,

muchas gracias.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="es">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <script>
         var islog = localStorage.getItem("islog"); 
         var acumularlog = localStorage.getItem("acumularlog");
         var control1; 
         var logInicial = localStorage.getItem("logInicial");
         var logResume;
         var acumullogResume;
         window.onload = function (){

         pantalla1 = document.getElementById("crono");
          if ((islog == null)||(islog == "Log Out")) {
            acumularlog2 = new Date();
            acumularlog2.setTime(acumularlog); 
            cc1 = Math.round(acumularlog2.getMilliseconds()/10);
            ss1 = acumularlog2.getSeconds();
            mm1 = acumularlog2.getMinutes();
            hh1 = acumularlog2.getHours()-18;
            if (cc1 < 10) {cc1 = "0"+cc1;}
            if (ss1 < 10) {ss1 = "0"+ss1;}
            if (mm1 < 10) {mm1 = "0"+mm1;}
            if (hh1 < 10) {hh1 = "0"+hh1;}
            pantalla1.innerHTML = hh1+" : "+mm1+" : "+ss1;}
          else { 
            start1 ()
          }}

    function start1 () {
    pantalla1 = document.getElementById("crono");
    if (islog == null) { 
      logInicial = new Date();
      localStorage.setItem("logInicial", logInicial.getTime());
      control1 = setInterval(cronometro1,10);
      islog = true;
      localStorage.setItem("islog", islog);
      document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log Out";}   
    else if (islog == true) {
      clearInterval(control1);
      islog = "Log Out";
      localStorage.setItem("islog", islog);
      document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log In";}
   else if (islog = "Log Out"){
    logActual2 = new Date() ;
    logActual2 = logActual2.getTime(); 
    localStorage.setItem("logActual2", logActual2);
      acumullogResume = logActual2 - localStorage.getItem("acumularlog");
      logResume = acumullogResume;
      logInicial = new Date();
      logInicial.setTime(logResume);
      control1 = setInterval(cronometro1,10);
      islog = true;
      localStorage.setItem("islog", islog);
      document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log Out";}
      }

  function cronometro1 () {
    logActual = new Date();
    acumularlog = logActual - logInicial;
    localStorage.setItem("acumularlog", acumularlog);
    acumularlog2 = new Date();
    acumularlog2.setTime(acumularlog); 
    cc1 = Math.round(acumularlog2.getMilliseconds()/10);
    ss1 = acumularlog2.getSeconds();
    mm1 = acumularlog2.getMinutes();
    hh1 = acumularlog2.getHours()-18;
    if (cc1 < 10) {cc1 = "0"+cc1;}
    if (ss1 < 10) {ss1 = "0"+ss1;} 
    if (mm1 < 10) {mm1 = "0"+mm1;}
    if (hh1 < 10) {hh1 = "0"+hh1;}
    pantalla1.innerHTML = hh1+" : "+mm1+" : "+ss1;}

 </script>

   <style>
    .crono_wrapper {text-align:center;width:200px;}
   </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="crono_wrapper">
       <h2 id='crono'>00 : 00 : 00</h2>
       <input type="button" value="Empezar" id="button1" onclick="start1() ">
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: para que manejas 3 banderas en la función start1 para  islog true, null, Log Out

Comment: las utilizo para disparar el cronometro, se verifica si el localstorage de la variable islog ="null",  es decir cuando el cronometro está parado (en cero), y en esa condición incia a contar el cronometro, cuando el cronometro está iniciado y contando si quiero pausarlo islog cambia a Log Out para indicarle a localstorage que el cronometro dejó de contar, islog true indica que el cronometro está contando lo que ayuda a saber si el boton inicia o detiene el cronometro, espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: No guardes el tiempo que lleva, sino el momento en que inició el cronómetro, así puedes realizar los cálculos necesarios para mostrar el valor real.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve validando tu código, primero, genera algunos errores debido a que pasas parámetros de números y boléanos  a el localStorage, este solo permite guardar string, por lo que si pasas un valor diferente intentara parsearlo siempre a string, para esos casos te recomiendo usar el JSON.stringify y JSON.parse para obtener el valor.

```
localStorage.setItem("islog", JSON.stringify(islog));
islog = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("islog"));
```

El otro problema que vi en tu código es que como todo lo intentas hacer en una sola función start1(), y solo dejas 3 valores en islog, entonces no puede reiniciar el contador bien cuando entra, desde  el window.onload. Por lo que genere un nuevo estatus "Reanudar" y modifique el de true, para dejarlo en cadena y todos sean de el mismo tipo.
Te dejo el codigo  y un ejemplo funcional, espero sea como tu solicitud.

https://playcode.io/678692/

```
window.onload = function (){
  pantalla1 = document.getElementById("crono");
  // Metí tu validación de carga inicial aquí, para evitar algún error de valor null, indefinido
  if(localStorage.getItem("logInicial")) {
    logInicial = new Date(); //Inicializo a new Date
    logInicial.setTime(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("logInicial"))); //Asigno el setTime de inicio
  }

  if(localStorage.getItem("islog")){
    islog = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("islog"));
  }

  if(localStorage.getItem("acumularlog")){
    acumularlog = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("acumularlog"));
  }
 
  if ((islog == null)||(islog === "Log Out")) {
    acumularlog2 = new Date();
    acumularlog2.setTime(acumularlog); 
    cc1 = Math.round(acumularlog2.getMilliseconds()/10);
    ss1 = acumularlog2.getSeconds();
    mm1 = acumularlog2.getMinutes();
    hh1 = acumularlog2.getHours()-18;
    if (cc1 < 10) {cc1 = "0"+cc1;}
    if (ss1 < 10) {ss1 = "0"+ss1;}
    if (mm1 < 10) {mm1 = "0"+mm1;}
    if (hh1 < 10) {hh1 = "0"+hh1;}
    pantalla1.innerHTML = hh1+" : "+mm1+" : "+ss1;
  }
  else {
    islog = "Reanudar"; //Agregue una bandera nueva, para indicar que se reanude.
    start1 ()
  }
}

function start1 () {
  pantalla1 = document.getElementById("crono");
  if (islog == null) {  //Si es para inicio
    logInicial = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem("logInicial", JSON.stringify(logInicial.getTime()));
    control1 = setInterval(cronometro1,10);
    islog = "Inciado"; //Modifique tu variable, para no mezclar boleanos y string.
    localStorage.setItem("islog", JSON.stringify(islog));
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log Out";
  }
  else if (islog === "Reanudar"){
    //Si viene del window Onload, es lo mismo de arriba
    //Quite el inicializar la variable logInicial y asignarla al localStorage, En realidad 
    //ya tiene Valor
    control1 = setInterval(cronometro1,10);
    islog = "Inciado";
    localStorage.setItem("islog", JSON.stringify(islog));
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log Out";
  }
  else if (islog == "Log Out"){
   //Si esta pausado, reanudar
    logActual2 = new Date() ;
    logActual2 = logActual2.getTime(); 
    localStorage.setItem("logActual2", logActual2);
    acumullogResume = logActual2 - JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("acumularlog"));
    logResume = acumullogResume;
    logInicial = new Date();
    logInicial.setTime(logResume);
    control1 = setInterval(cronometro1,10);
    islog = true;
    localStorage.setItem("islog", JSON.stringify(islog));
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log Out";
  }
  else if (islog = "Inciado") { 
    //Si esta inciado Pausa
    clearInterval(control1);
    islog = "Log Out";
    localStorage.setItem("islog", JSON.stringify(islog));
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "Log In";
  }
}

function cronometro1 () {
  //Unicamente meti las los JSON.stringify
  logActual = new Date();
  acumularlog = logActual - logInicial;
  localStorage.setItem("acumularlog", JSON.stringify(acumularlog));
  acumularlog2 = new Date();
  acumularlog2.setTime(acumularlog);
  idx=idx + 1;
  cc1 = Math.round(acumularlog2.getMilliseconds()/10);
  ss1 = acumularlog2.getSeconds();
  mm1 = acumularlog2.getMinutes();
  hh1 = acumularlog2.getHours()-18;
  if (cc1 < 10) {cc1 = "0"+cc1;}
  if (ss1 < 10) {ss1 = "0"+ss1;} 
  if (mm1 < 10) {mm1 = "0"+mm1;}
  if (hh1 < 10) {hh1 = "0"+hh1;}
  pantalla1.innerHTML = hh1+" : "+mm1+" : "+ss1;
}
```

Comment: esto ayuda para evitar tantos condicionales `"0"+Math.round(acumularlog2.getMilliseconds()/10).slice(-2)` donde si es `10` quedarias `010` y obteniendo los 2 ultimos `10` y en caso de `9` seria `09`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, tengo una duda más, con el código que me das en el ejemplo, si lo dejo contando  cierro la pestaña el cronometro si cuenta el tiempo que estuvo con la pestaña cerrada, pero en una de esas veces por error recargué la pagina y lo que hizo fue sumar de nuevo el tiempo que estuvo "afuera", por ejemplo, el cronometro va en "0:02:00" cuando lo cierro, la pestaña se queda cerrada 1 minuto, cuando lo abro de nuevo el cronometro dice "0:03:00" (lo cual es correcto), pero si lo pauso, luego lo reanudo y luego recargo la pagina me dice "0:05:00", deberia ser "0:03:04" no sé como hacerle.